# Not getting correct timezone in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I have set my system data time to Asia/Kolkata and it is:

```
Date: 2015-06-12
Time: 12:07:43.548
```

Now i have written following program in Java 8

```
ZoneId paris = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris");
LocalDateTime localtDateAndTime = LocalDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime dateAndTimeInParis  = ZonedDateTime.of(localtDateAndTime, paris );
System.out.println("Current date and time in a particular timezone : " + dateAndTimeInParis  );
```

When i run the code it shows following time for Paris:

```
Current date and time in a particular timezone :    

2015-06-12T12:07:43.548+02:00[Europe/Paris]
```

The above Europe/Paris is same as of Asia/Kolkata. Could anyone please explain where i am doing wrong?

**Update**:  I prefer not using class from another Java package; as i have heard that this package java.time have enough functionalities to handle maximum date time jobs and i hope this one is included :)

Comment: Can you try setting the TimeZone.setDefault to right timezone first. TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("<Required timezone here>"));

Comment: Calendar calParis = Calendar.getInstance();  calParis.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));System.out.println("Time in Paris: " + calParis.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
        + calParis.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

Comment: @Himanshu:
if i set it; then i need to reset it again and again every time when i need to change Timezone.

Comment: @Java-DK: Thanks, but i prefer using Java 8 Time API only.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj `TimeZone` belongs to the Calendar API, not the Java Time API, so what you suggest would have no effect...

Comment: Java time api is introduced in Java-8 I guess. Haven't upgraded myself to Java-8 yet. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `LocalDateTime` is a date and time without a timezone. When you create a `ZonedDateTime` object out of it, you're explicitly attaching a timezone to the `LocalDateTime`.

It's not going to convert from your timezone to the `Europe/Paris` timezone; note that the `LocalDateTime` does not have a timezone at all; it doesn't know that you mean it to be `Asia/Kolkata`.

If you want to convert from Kolkata time to Paris time, start with a `ZonedDateTime` that uses the `Asia/Kolkata` timezone:

```
// Current time in Asia/Kolkata
ZonedDateTime kolkata = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));

// Convert to the same time in Europe/Paris
ZonedDateTime paris = kolkata.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
```

(edit, thanks JBNizet): If you just want "now" in `Europe/Paris` time, you can do:

```
ZonedDateTime paris = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
```

Comment: Exactly. What the OP wants is `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"))`

Comment: @JBNizet That would also work, if you just want "now" in Paris time.

Comment: @Jesper: Thanks, Let me try